# Dealing with non-standard SMTP ports with sendmail -t

Tags: email, sendmail, exim

On my development machine, I have a special kind of SMTP server running on non-standard port which is used for testing purposes.

On my virtual machine I'm trying to push a message to that SMTP server by using Exim4's sendmail app:

```
selenium-node$ sendmail -t
To: root@my-development-machine.testingnetwork.local:2525
From: apache@my-selenium-node.testingnetwork.local
Subject: Test message

Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
selenium-node$
```

However, it looks that default SMTP server on my-development-machine.testingnetwork.local:25 receives my message instead.

Is there a clean and natural way to do what I'm trying for? Modifying some configs on my-selenium-node.testingnetwork.local is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SMTP *always* goes to TCP/25 unless the mail delivery agent (here, `sendmail` as implemented by Exim) is specifically configured to send the mail to some custom port. There is *no* means to set the port like there is in URL from the mail user agent that talks to the mail delivery agent. Options thus are limited to [reconfiguring Exim to send to a different port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655281/exim4-nonstandard-ports) or to use some other mail sending program to direct the mail elsewhere, such as `ssmtp` with configuration in `ssmtp.conf` along the lines of

```
mailhub=my-development-machine.testingnetwork.local:2525
```

and then piping the message to `ssmtp`. Another option would be to use a SMTP client module in some programming language; these may support sending to arbitrary TCP ports.